# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient#GetAsync throws an incomplete exception when invalid credentials are used with basic authentication

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on a Windows Runtime Component which makes API calls. Until earlier today I used the `HttpClient` and related models from `System.Net` but switched over to `Windows.Web` instead to leverage the WinRT streams.

Aside from changing the `using` statements, swapping `HttpContent` to `IHttpContent` and using the `WindowsRuntimeExtensions` to change my `IInputStream` to `Stream` for JSON.NET, I didn't have to do anything special. However suddenly 3 out of my 16 tests fail whereas previously everything worked.

All 3 (integration) tests validate that I receive an error response when logging in with invalid credentials. There are other tests that include logging in as well (but with valid credentials) and they work just fine. The given error message is of type `AggregateException` and has as message

> `System.AggregateException`: One or more errors occurred. ---> `System.Exception`: Element not found.
>
> A dialog cannot be displayed because the parent window handle has not been set.

The exception contains HRESULT values. The outerexception has value `-2146233088` which corresponds to `0x80131500` while the innerexception has `-2147023728` which corresponds to `0x80070490`. Neither of those are a known error code on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298646).

Following investigation:

- `0x80131500` [corresponds to](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__hresults.cs#57) `COR_E_EXCEPTION`
- `0x80070490` [corresponds to](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/errornotfound-0x80070490-when-trying-to-install/d0c53c85-39b5-4b9d-936d-7ec2c353b208) `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`

Stacktrace:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at xx.Models.Requests.GetRequest.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\jeroen\Github\Windows-app\xx\xx\Models\Requests\Request.cs:line 17

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at xx.ApiDispatcher.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\jeroen\Github\Windows-app\xx\xx\ApiDispatcher.cs:line 40

 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at xx.ApiDispatcher.Execute[TCallResult,TResponseObject](ApiCall`2 call) in c:\Users\jeroen\Github\Windows-app\xx\xx\ApiDispatcher.cs:line 22
```

Originally my question was worded somewhat differently because the actual problem seemed to be hidden. I have found out that the GET request by the `HttpClient` returns back to the caller instead of awaiting the result of the call (and executing the rest of the method).

In my project, executing the line `var data = await myHttpClient.GetAsync(url);` will return to the calling method with a non-constructed object and subsequent lines that come after the `GetAsync()` call are simply not executed.

Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to stop it from going back did not make a difference.

The `AggregateException` is thrown when a user tries to login with invalid credentials. For some reason the `HttpClient` decides to throw an exception then without giving me a return value I could use. The problem here is that it does not tell me what kind of exception: catching `COMException`, `TaskCanceledException`, `AggregateException` and `Exception` only trigger the latter.

I have also found out that asynchronous integration tests do not work well with the multithreaded MSTest environment, so that explains several other failed tests that I had (but worked just fine individually)

I also, finally, have an example that demonstrates the problem (but I can't provide a webservice that takes basic auth)!

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(new Test().Do().AsTask().Result);
}

public sealed class Test
{
   public IAsyncOperation<bool> Do()
   {
       return DoSomething().AsAsyncOperation();
   } 

   private async Task<bool> DoSomething()
   {
       var client = new HttpClient();
       var info = "jeroen.vannevel@something.com:nopass";
       var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(info));
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Basic", token);

       var data = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://mytestdomain/v2/apikey?format=Json"));
       return true;
   }
}
```

Executing this code with a valid password will return `true` while an invalid password will throw an `AggregateException`.

Right now I am working around the problem by catching a general `Exception` around the call to `GetAsync()` but this is very rudimentary and I'd like to know why this incomplete exception is thrown in the first place.

Comment: Could you try setting different authentication credentials: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: that is part of the `System.Net.Http` namespace and not compatible with the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` unless I am overlooking something.

Comment: Right, you're using `Windows.Web`. My mistake.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `HttpHandler` and settings its `Credentials` property, then passing it to `HttpClient`? `var client = new HttpClient(handler)`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: that's `System.Net` as well.

Comment: Sorry, i ment an `IHttpFilter`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.ihttpfilter

Comment: I have made an `IHttpFilter` but I don't see how it can make a difference: it still passes on the credentials to the eventual `GetAsync` method; it just does it in a later stage. Setting the credentials in the filter did not change the result.

Comment: I think i got it this time :)

Comment: If appropriate, simply adding "Pragma:no-cache" to my request header fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After reconstructing your example and playing around, I figured out what happens.

```
var data = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://mytestdomain/v2/apikey?format=Json"));
```

The `GetAsync` method invokes the HTTP request with invalid credentials. What happens is that the returned request tries to look for a window where you can enter the correct credentials, but doesn't find one. Hence it throws an `Element Not Found` while searching for that window.

This can be fixed by creating a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` and setting the `AllowUI` property to `false` and then passing it to the `HttpClient`:

```
private async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    var httpBaseFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter
    {
        AllowUI = false
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(httpBaseFilter);
    var info = "jeroen.vannevel@something.com:nopass";
    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(info));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Basic", token);

    var data = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://mytestdomain/v2/apikey?format=Json"));
    return true;
}
```

[image: Response after adding HttpBaseProtocolFilter]

Comment: I appreciate the thorough help! You are entirely correct, this solved it. I'll leave the bounty open for some more time so there will be more views for your answer but rest assured that you'll get it.

Comment: Does this behavior depend on the platform of the device sending the request? When I send this request from Win RT tablet I get "Element not found" error (and setting AllowUI to false worked there) but in WP device I got the correct error: UnAuthorized (even without setting AllowUI to false).

Comment: @Ashish Not sure, I've never tried dispatching a request from WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `AllowUI` on `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` to `false` will stop this error.

If however you do want a dialog box to display, allowing the user to enter credentials, then the web request needs to be started on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the exception is actually thrown by your call to EnsureSuccessStatusCode.

Did you try adding HttpResponseMessage class  EnsureSuccessStatusCode() method and check.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode.aspx

After this line:

```
var data = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://mytestdomain/v2/apikey?format=Json"));
date.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: The exception is thrown at the `await` point. It has nothing to do with `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`